# Sql server select first less value

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have table data like this

```
column1   Column2  Column3    Column4
    2        3        10          asdfas
    2        3        12          asdfas
    2        3        15          asdfas
    2        3        17          asdfas
```

I have taken them in a list Listdata

```
Listdata.Where(x => x.Column3 < 17).FirstOrDefault();
```

It is returning the first row how should i make it return second last row. ie with column3 15

Comment: The question could be clearer - second last row, out of those that satisfy Column3 < 17, would be 12 not 15.  You probably meant the last row satisfying the condition.  Right?

Comment: Last when ordered by which criteria? Unless an OrderBy statement is used, the server will return rows without a specific order. Typically, this will be the order they are saved on disk. If a clustered index is used, they will return in that order

Answer (score 2):

```
Listdata
    .Where(x => x.Column3 < 17)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Column3)
    .Take(2)
    .Last();
```

Comment: @andmor thaks it just striked to me after asking the question

Answer (score 0):

```
Listdata.Where(x => x.Column3 < 17)
.Reverse()
.Skip(1)
.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Listdata.OrderByDescending(x => x.Column3).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

OR

```
Listdata.Reverse().Skip(1).Take(1);
```